# Select all NOT in requirement, Linq to SQL

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have a simple set of tables...

List
- Id

Items
- Id

Entries
- EntryId
- ListId
- ItemId

I'm trying to design a Linq query that will take a given ListId and return all of the Items that do not have an Entry with that ListId on it. It sounds pretty simple, but it keeps coming up wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select all Items you could do something like this.

```
var x = Items.Where(item => !Entries.Any(entry => entry.ItemID == item.ID && entry.ListID == listID));
```

Comment: Well, that just returns entries, not actual items.

Comment: Okay yeah I thought you might want the items, I added the example for that and will remove the first example.

Comment: ItemID == item.ID && 

This part, I'm not sure what is going on here. It doesn't really work, and I'm not sure what "item.ID' is supposed to be substituting here. Can I bother you to clarify?

Comment: Nevermind, I typed in the data wrong... I think this is exactly what I am looking for. I'm trying to read it closely to see if I understand what it is doing.

Comment: Sure, you are selecting from the Items table predicated on the fact that you only want items where there aren't any Entries matching an Item.ID where the Entry's ListID is the listID you are trying to exclude.

Answer (score 0):

```
var itemsToExclude = from dc.Lists in dc select l;

var x= from Entries in dc select e where !itemsToExclude.Contains(e.ListId)
```